# Use variable to set property of object in CoffeeScript/Framer

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

I'm new to Framer and having an extremely annoying issue I've spent hours trying to solve.

I'm trying to build a statement that changes the opacity property of an object with the name passed through the variable `sectionToLoad`. I'm able to log the statement perfectly in the console but it won't render. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
HideSection = (sectionToLoad) ->
PossibleSections = ["layerA", "layerB", "layerC", "layerD"]
for i in [0..PossibleSections.length - 1]
    if PossibleSections[i] != sectionToLoad
        console.log(PossibleSections[i])
        PossibleSections[i].opacity = 1
    else
        console.log(sectionToLoad + ".opacity = 1")
        # WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK?
        sectionToLoad.opacity = 0

HideSection("layerB")

#BUT THIS DOES SOME REASON
# layerB.opacity = 1
```

Here's my framer file http://share.framerjs.com/9pv42mi6c99n/

Comment: `sectionToLoad` is the *string* `'layerB'`, not the *object* `layerB`. Where do the `layerA` ... `layerD` objects come from? Can you change `PossibleSections` to be a string-to-object map instead of an array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was using strings instead of objects. Literally the addition of unnecessary quotations.

`layerB` was the object, `"layerB"` was the string. Thanks to the above comment for the clue.

This is working code.

```
HideSection = (sectionToLoad) ->
PossibleSections = [layerA, layerB, layerC, layerD]
for i in [0..PossibleSections.length - 1]
    if PossibleSections[i] != sectionToLoad
        console.log(PossibleSections[i])
        PossibleSections[i].opacity = 1
    else
        console.log(sectionToLoad + ".opacity = 1")
        sectionToLoad.opacity = 0

HideSection(layerC)
```